# How to count number of records active in all dates in Excel?

Tags: excel, count

I have a three column table: ID, Start Date and End Date. They are an employee list with 3.000 names ranging from 1906 (Start Date) to 2015 (End Date).

I want to know the total number of employees yearly from 1906 to 2015. I have tried everything and looked for several options of COUNTIFS()

UPDATE:
This question is unique in several aspects. One of them is the conversion from full date to year. The person who tagged the question as already answered failed to indicate a similar one.

Comment: have you considered using a pivot table?

Comment: Are the dates **full dates** or only years??

Comment: First, the question is unique as it needs several operations not displayed in other questions.

Comment: Second, only in years.

Comment: This question is not unique and has been answered numerous times. The post referenced counts per month; it should be a small matter to convert that to counting by years.

Comment: Can you put sample data? It will help to understand your requirement. You may put screenshot also.